# How give connect rights on OS X ftp server for non admin account user

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, ftp-server

To enable the FTP server on OS X, you have to load the FTP service like this:

```
sudo -s launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist
```

To stop the service you need to **unload** the service with the same command:

```
sudo -s launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist
```

But this only works for admin account users. How to enable standard account ?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of googling, I finally found a special command : **dseditgroup**. If your admin user is **admin** and the standard account which want to share folders by ftp is **ftpuser**, you can write this cmd :

```
dseditgroup -o edit -u admin -a ftpuser com.apple.access_ftp
```

The command while ask you the password for ftpuser to be able to use ftp service. If there is no message (no error massage) you operation is donne. You can try the ftp connexion with your ftpuser like this :

```
ftp ftpuser@localhot
```

When you give the ftpuser password you should be connected to it's account.